# (Java Minecraft 1.14) Trouble giving a scoreboard tag to a /given item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have the command `/give @p minecraft:nether_star{Tags:["catalyst"],Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:channeling",lvl:1}],display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"Catalyst\",\"color\":\"yellow\"}"}} 1`, which works predictably and gives me a nether star correctly named, colored, and enchanted.

However, when I run `/execute as @e[tag=catalyst] run say hi` with the nether star on the ground it doesn't say anything. Furthermore, when I run `/execute as @e[type=item] run tag @s list` I get 'Nether star has no tags". What am I doing wrong to not be able to select the star based on it's scoreboard tag?

Comment: I think your questions are getting worse. :( Please do your own research before asking here.

Comment: @Fabian The item entity wiki doesn't mention the `Tags:[]` nbt at all, so there is nothing to be found there. Same with the player.dat format wiki. The tags section of the scoreboard wiki doesn't mention anything regarding items except that "Scoreboard tags are a simple list of single-word strings stored directly in the  Tags data tag of an entity." I assumed that the fact that I *could* give a player an item with a scoreboard tag (through `Tags:[]`) meant it must apply to the item entity. I apologize for the mistake, although I do think three downvotes and a chiding comment are a bit harsh.

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do here, you can't tag items in inventories and you can't use `@e` for items in inventories. The item entity part of "chunk format" does mention tags, in the section of tags that apply to all entities.

Comment: I gave myself a nether star with the `Tags:[]` nbt of "catalyst". Tag meaning not `tag:{}` the nbt but the scoreboard tag, which the chunk format does not mention. I expected to be able to select the item, when thrown onto the ground, with this tag and @e, because it would be an entity with the tag "catalyst". Obviously this is incorrect, but raises the question of why you can `/give` a player an item with a scoreboard tag.

Comment: "I gave myself a nether star with the Tags:[]" No, you didn't. The `Tags` NBT tag just does nothing for items in inventories, it gets deleted instantly. You could have just as well written "`{bla:blubb}`", it would do the same: Nothing.

Comment: So if you attempt to put an invalid nbt tag onto an item it deletes it rather than raising an error? That explains a lot of things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep, NBT validation isn't very far in Minecraft yet. If you have doubts, you can always use `/data get` right afterwards. And no, not `@e[type=item]`, but `@s`, because it's in your data.

Answer (score 2):

Items in inventories are just properties of the containing block/entity, not an entity on their own.

Comment: So item entities do not have the same scoreboard tags as the item in the inventory? How/why is it possible to give them tags with `Tags:[]` then?

Comment: It's not. Scoreboard tags do not exist in inventories, they are a thing that applies only to entities. Stuff inside inventories is just information, like effects or health. You can't tag your health and you can't tag items in an inventory. The item entity (drop) is something else, it's an entity that basically has one inventory slot.